# 'ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture ???' even when it's there

Tags: c++, macos, boost, linker, g++

I'm having this weird issue trying to add a reference to a boost module in C++. First of all, you need to know that I'm playing a little with C++, so maybe it's a super easy-rookie thing that I have missed.

This is my environment, so you get more context: Mac OS Mavericks, with the MacPorts port of boost 1.55 and g++-mp-4.8. I'm currently linking and using `boost_system-mt` and `boost_filesystem-mt`.

The thing is I'm working in an ongoing project, and it's using boost all along and compiling fine. I'm trying to convert an `utf8` string to `Latin1`, so I included `boost/locale.hpp`, and added `-lboost_locale-mt` to the linker params. For the task I'm doing:

```
boost::locale::conv::from_utf<char>(value, "Latin1")
```

So far so good, it compiles fine, but then when the linking should be done, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > boost::locale::conv::from_utf<char>(char const*, char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::locale::conv::method_type)", referenced from:
      clsByteQueue::WriteUnicodeStringFixed(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) in clsByteQueue.o
      clsByteQueue::WriteUnicodeString(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) in clsByteQueue.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The linker is running with the following command:

```
g++-mp-4.8 -fstack-protector -ggdb -o "bin/foobar" <all compiled.o files goes here> -L/opt/local/lib/ -levent -levent_core -levent_extra -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_locale-mt
```

The thing is, I checked and `/opt/local/lib/libboost_locale-mt.a` not only exists but also is compiled for the proper architecture:

```
$ lipo -info /opt/local/lib/libboost_locale-mt.a
input file /opt/local/lib/libboost_locale-mt.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: /opt/local/lib/libboost_locale-mt.a is architecture: x86_64
```

Also, I made a search in the file for from_utf and the following symbol appeared:

```
$ otool -tv /opt/local/lib/libboost_locale-mt.a | grep from_utf
__ZN5boost6locale4conv8from_utfIcEENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEEPKT_SC_RKS9_NS1_11method_typeE:
```

After unmangling it using `c++filt` I could verify that is the same symbol that the linker is not finding (unless that __1 means something?):

```
$ c++filt __ZN5boost6locale4conv8from_utfIcEENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEEPKT_SC_RKS9_NS1_11method_typeE
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > boost::locale::conv::from_utf<char>(char const*, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, boost::locale::conv::method_type)
```

So, I'm pretty much clueless by now.

Can you guys help me to find out what is wrong, or at least what else may I try?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `__1` does mean something. It means it's from clang's libc++, not libstdc++ which is what g++ uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `boost::locale` was compiled with clang and libc++, which is the default compiler and standard library on Mac OS X, while your program was compiled with g++ and libstdc++, which is g++'s standard library. The two standard libraries are not binary compatible.

You need to either compile everything with clang and libc++, or get a version of boost that's compiled with g++ and libstdc++.

Comment: Good catch, thanks a lot! I was also getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when a boost exception was raised. Now I understand why. Is there any way to check this in the future other than that obscure "__1" namespace in between?